# Ignore all those "free" wifi access points

Tags: wi-fi

This has probably been asked before but I was unable to find anything relevant with searches.

My problem is, I can be using my phone with my almost unlimited 4G data, quite happily, but if I pass too close to a place offering "free" wifi, or if a bus with "free" wifi on board passes me, all of a sudden I get redirected to  a "You must sign in.." page.

I don't want  to sign in, I don't WANT to use their "free" wifi. I want to continue using my 4G data, without having to go through the rigamarole of disabling wifi every time I leave the house. I want it to IGNORE those "free" wifi things.

Can this be achieved in any meaningful way?

Comment: Which Android version? Check your Wifi settings (disable notification for free Wifi networks) and delete all saved Wifi networks you don't want t connect to.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but if you don't mind keeping location enabled all the time, you may set up a Tasker profile to disable wifi when you leave the house.